# how to reset an axios.post for multiple queries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a button that triggers an `axios.post` to an API endpoint. The button works the first time it is used (the `console.log(res.data.userdata[0].txHash)` is successful).

If I change the state (`this.state.hashOutput`) and press the button again, an error that `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'txHash' of undefined` occurs. There are no errors on the server.

code:

```
  handleOnClick() {
      const searchValue = this.state.hashOutput;
      axios.post("https://myapi.net/searchDB", {
          searchValue: searchValue
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data);
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }
```

Any thoughts? I don't know where to begin researching this. Thanks!

Comment: When you change the state at that time what is the result from the API ?

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'txHash' of undefined`

I've added the exact error to the OP for clarity. Thanks for looking at this :)

Comment: Can you showing, the state ?, don't look console.log(res.data.userdata[0].txHash);, but console.log(res) or catch error to looking the error response

Comment: The problem is on the server side, because there is no txHash in the response, so you have to check your backend. The error says that your response.data object does not contains "userdata" property

Comment: I did a plain console.log(res.data) and it is indeed sending an empty array on the second try. I will look at the server code. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The first API call is grabbing data from my database, the second API call is returning an empty array (server side). I will open a new question with the server specific code. thanks thanks thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure whether the response has an array of data or a single object?
In any case, it is recommended that you check before accessing values like so.

```
  handleOnClick() {
      const searchValue = this.state.hashOutput;
      axios.post("https://myapi.net/searchDB", {
          searchValue: searchValue
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data.userdata && res.data.userdata[0] && res.data.userdata[0].txHash);  // make sure the value is available before accessing the property 
        });
    }
  }
```

Each post is independent and you would not have to `reset` as mentioned in the post. Try logging `res` first.

Comment: yes, you are right that the server is not returning a value on the second API call. Will open a separate question. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

`txHash` is a property of `res.data.userdata[x]` as depicted in your program and the error clearly says `Cannot read property 'txHash' of undefined`, ergo, `res.data.userdata[x]` is undefined, which means that the search result received from the server didn't contain any data which in turn means your search parameters doesn't match to any value in database, so it is a case of "search result(s) not found" and shouldn't cause any error on backend side which is the case. You should put a check on the frontend side and handle it appropriately.

Log the result like this and check out the result for yourself:

```
console.log("Data: ", res.data);
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the server is returning data the first time, but not the second. I accepted the other answer because the posted first, but I do really appreciate you taking the time to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but see if you had bind the handleOnClick function in constructor. Sometimes this might give undefined error.

```
this.handleOnClick=this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
```

Please check.

Thanks

Comment: You dont need to bind anything, because Vue.js resolves context by itself.

Comment: But I think he talking about reactjs.

Comment: This is react. Yes, handleOnClick is bound in that way. It works the first time, but returns an error if the state is changed and clicked a second time. Thanks for taking a look :)